# Cannot Fetch Postgres 9.0 Package For Install in Ubuntu/CloudFoundry

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-9.0

I'm trying to install CloudFoundry (VCAP) on an ubuntu 10.04 server instance.
Following these directions: http://blog.modeltwozero.com/2011/05/running-cloud-foundry-on-amazon-ec2-or.html

Unfortunately the build command complains that Postgres 9.0 doesn't exist.  I've tried to install Postgres 9.0 separately but can't succeed with either of these posts & everyone seems to point to the same directory.

Perhaps the directory is old?  I'd be grateful for any ideas!

Here is the log when I try to build:

```
$ bash < <(curl -s -k -B https://raw.github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/master/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev_setup)

Installing wget...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
wget is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Checking web connectivity.
Installing prerequisites...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
ruby is already the newest version.
ruby-dev is already the newest version.
libopenssl-ruby is already the newest version.
rdoc is already the newest version.
ri is already the newest version.
irb is already the newest version.
build-essential is already the newest version.
ssl-cert is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Installing chef...
true
Installing blobstore_client...
true
Installing rake...
true
Installing git...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
git-core is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

Lanching chef...
Installing deployment devbox, cloudfoundry home dir is /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry
RUN LIST = role[cloudfoundry]role[nats_server]role[ccdb]role[cloud_controller]role[postgresql_gateway]role[redis_gateway]role[redis_node]role[uaadb]role[filesystem_gateway]role[mongodb_gateway]role[health_manager]role[router]role[rabbitmq_gateway]role[mysql_gateway]role[mysql_node]role[vblob_gateway]role[vblob_node]role[postgresql_node]role[dea]role[mongodb_node]role[rabbitmq_node]role[uaa]role[stager]
[2012-08-17T06:38:37+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.12.0 ***
[2012-08-17T06:38:38+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[cloudfoundry]", "role[nats_server]", "role[ccdb]", "role[cloud_controller]", "role[postgresql_gateway]", "role[redis_gateway]", "role[redis_node]", "role[uaadb]", "role[filesystem_gateway]", "role[mongodb_gateway]", "role[health_manager]", "role[router]", "role[rabbitmq_gateway]", "role[mysql_gateway]", "role[mysql_node]", "role[vblob_gateway]", "role[vblob_node]", "role[postgresql_node]", "role[dea]", "role[mongodb_node]", "role[rabbitmq_node]", "role[uaa]", "role[stager]"] from JSON
[2012-08-17T06:38:38+00:00] INFO: Run List is [role[cloudfoundry], role[nats_server], role[ccdb], role[cloud_controller], role[postgresql_gateway], role[redis_gateway], role[redis_node], role[uaadb], role[filesystem_gateway], role[mongodb_gateway], role[health_manager], role[router], role[rabbitmq_gateway], role[mysql_gateway], role[mysql_node], role[vblob_gateway], role[vblob_node], role[postgresql_node], role[dea], role[mongodb_node], role[rabbitmq_node], role[uaa], role[stager]]
[2012-08-17T06:38:38+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [deployment, essentials, ruby, cloudfoundry, nats_server, postgresql, postgresql::system, ccdb, ruby::ruby18, nginx, staging_manifest, cloud_controller, postgresql::gateway, redis::gateway, redis, redis::node, redis::backup, uaadb, filesystem::default, filesystem::gateway, mongodb::gateway, health_manager, router, rabbitmq::gateway, mysql::gateway, mysql, mysql::node, mysql::backup, vblob::gateway, node::node06, vblob, vblob::node, postgresql::service, postgresql::node, postgresql::backup, dea, imagemagick, mongodb, mongodb::node, mongodb::backup, rabbitmq, rabbitmq::node, java, maven, tomcat, uaa, stager]
[2012-08-17T06:38:38+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for ip-10-160-245-8.us-west-1.compute.internal
[2012-08-17T06:38:38+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2012-08-17T06:38:38+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
gpg: requesting key 8683D8A2 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 8683D8A2: "Launchpad PPA for Martin Pitt" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql-common/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server                                                                                                                                              [ OK ] 
[2012-08-17T06:38:54+00:00] ERROR: The running postgresql listening on port 5433 could not match the version: 9.0, try another port
[2012-08-17T06:38:54+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2012-08-17T06:38:54+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you tried to install the Postgres DB as mentioned here: http://codingforme.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/installing-postgresql-database-and-pgadmin-iii-in-ubuntu-12-04/ ?

Unless the package is outdated, this should work for you, mate.